# Show functions in Eclipse's Project Explorer

Tags: eclipse, function, methods, project, explorer

I accidently closed the Project Explorer in Eclipse and the opportunity to expand all functions used in my php files is missing when I opened it again via Window -> Show View.

Does anyone know how to get this back?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO there is no settings for this in eclipse.

When last instance of a view is closed from all perspective, then it saves only the position of the view but not the collapsed or expanded state within this view.

However to stop this behaviour **keep open this view always** in any of the perspective opened.
You can also create new perspective using Window->Save Perspective as..

Answer (score 0):

Under the project manager view menu, under "project presentation", check to see that you are in "hierarchical". When I lost the function list in my Java project, it brought back the function list.